# MSSQL: Swapping in a table move the auto stats from the old to the new

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ddl

We have a table that gets rebuilt from scratch a few times a day including indexes.  When the building is complete we swap the new version of the table for the old one using sp_rename.  The one thing that does not get moved is any auto created statistics. Does any one know of a way to move those from one table to another?

Comment: What edition of SQL server are you using? You could use partitions to do the work and not lose your stats. I think you need Enterprise edition.

Comment: We are using 2012 enterprise but I don't think partitions will help us. The rebuild does noo just add rows it also updates rows that are already existing in the table

Comment: I suppose you could "round robin" your production table and a work table...never really dropping either. The stats would be reasonable. Not sure what happens to stats if you truncate table...but it might be worth playing with.